# Ionic 2 - global NavBar for the app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In Ionic 1, we have the ability to define an `<ion-nav-bar>` above an `<ion-nav-view>`, which serves as a generic nav bar for the entire app and we could turn it off on a per-view basis (using `ionNavView`'s `hideNavBar=true|false`.

It appears in Ionic 2 we have to insert an `<ion-nav-bar>` per page - and cannot have a global nav bar for the entire app. Is that correct, or am I missing a trick?

If so - it seems like a lot of duplicated code?

Also, it appears you do not have the ability for the NavBar to build its own back button, and you have to write the own mark-up for the back button yourself (per page) which, again, seems like a lot of code duplicate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Just like @mhartington says:

> **There is no way to create a global ion-navbar**, as this is done on
>   purpose. The point of having a navbar defined for each component is so
>   that we can properly animate the titles, navbar background color (if
>   you change them) and animate other properties needed.

And about creating a custom directive to avoid duplicating `ion-navbar` html code:

> That will still creat errors with how angular2 content projection
>   works. We have several issues that have been open when people try this
>   and **the best answer is to not do it**.

---

**NOT recommended solution:**

In order to avoid duplicating so much code, you can create your own custom component for the navbar.

Create a `navbar.html` with this code:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>MyApp</ion-title>
  <button  menuToggle="right" end>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>

  <ion-buttons *ngIf="!hideCreateButton" end>
    <button (click)="createNew()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

And then in the `navbar.ts`:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {CreateNewPage} from '../../pages/create-new/create-new';

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'build/components/navbar/navbar.html',
    inputs: ['hideCreateButton']
})
export class CustomNavbar {

    public hideCreateButton: string;

    constructor(private nav: NavController) {
    }

    createNew(): void {
        this.nav.setRoot(CreateNewPage, {}, { animate: true, direction: 'forward' });
    }
}
```

By declaring the `hideCreateButton` as an `input` of the `Component`, you can decide in which pages show that button and in which ones should not be visible. So in this way, you can send information to tell the component how it should be, and customize it for each page.

So if you want to add the navbar in a page (without modifying the default template, so showing the create button) you just have to add the `navbar` element (binded to our custom component by us in the `selector` property):

```
<navbar></navbar>

<ion-content>
  ...
</ion-content>
```

And if you want to hide the create button (or modify you navbar like you want to) your page will look like this one:

```
<navbar [hideCreateButton]="hidebutton()"></navbar>

<ion-content>
   ...
</ion-content>
```

And remember that the `hideButton()` should be defined in your `customPage.ts` like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/create-new/create-new.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class CreateNewPage{

    private hideCreateButton: boolean = true;

    public hidebutton(): boolean {
        return this.hideCreateButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer - thanks. Something now achievable as of Ionic v2-beta 8 :)

Comment: `Something now achievable as of Ionic v2-beta`. Can't find anything in the docs about this. Have you got a link for this?

Comment: Yes, you can read about how to make nested component interact in [this tutorial from Angular 2 docs.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html)

Comment: This is not correct. There is no way to create a global ion-navbar, as this is done on purpose. The point of having a navbar defined for each component is so that we can properly animate the titles, navbar background color (if you change them) and animate other properties needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info @mhartington! Maybe the answer is ambiguous, I'm not creating a _global_ ion-navbar, I'm just creating a _custom directive_ called _navbar_ so instead of adding all that html code (the ion-navbar, ion-title, ion-butons, and so on) I just add `<navbar></navbar>` in each component.

Comment: That will still creat errors with how angular2 content projection works. We have several issues that have been open when people try this and the best answer is to not do it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with that information. Thanks again @mhartington :)

Comment: @mhartington Do we still not use this approach (2.0.0-rc.0)? What would be the errors ? Can you provide some link ?

Comment: This example seems a fair bit out dated at this point.  1) There's no <ion-header> tag, which i believe is part of the framework now.  2) It's unclear what "*navbar" is -- I don't think that's a thing anymore either.

Comment: I've been struggling to simply extract ion-navbar into a component.  I made a demo app doing just that and showing the UI issues I've been hitting: https://github.com/josh-m-sharpe/navbar-demo

Comment: How would I change the title for each page for this component?

Comment: @Whitecat Please notice that it's not recommended to use a component for the header, since it may cause some issues as **mhartington** mentioned. That being said, you could add the title as a new `@Input` of the component (you can find more information in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)).

Comment: This is a nice alternative solution, on the other hand, it has a bug. (i know you also mentioned that it is not recommended). I have tried it and it is causing overlap on status bar. When i add the ion-navbar directly it works perfectly. So i will follow your advice as using the ion-navbar per page.

Comment: @EbruGüngör Yeah, it's not the best approach when dealing with several pages (and with the same logic repeated on each page) but when you start learning how page transitions work behind the scenes, you can understand why Ionic made things that way. Btw, if you need to add a button or something with a given behavior, remember that you could use a directive to add the behavior to that button, and avoid duplicating the code on each page.

Comment: @sebaferreras thanks for the remark, i was thinking what to do with the global methods from navbar.

Comment: @EbruGüngör something similar has been done **[in this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164262/global-function-in-ionic-2-angular-2)**.

Comment: @sebaferreras btw, i tried to upvote more but it does not work, since i upvoted days ago :)

Answer (score 8):

For ionic 3+

What I did to solve this was simply use a custom component.

```
ionic generate component navbar
```

- Add the relevant navbar html to your component template
- Add any other functionality to your component .ts file
- Modify your selector to something relevant, (if used command above it
  should just default to 'navbar'.
- Also add the component to your app.module.ts declarations

Then in any of your page templates, simply use it as a custom element
e.g

```
<navbar></navbar>
<ion-content padding>
   ...
</ion-content/>
```

Comment: Did that work? When I tried it, the header wasn't working correctly for me (due to styling rules I guessed). I didn't spend tremendous amounts of time, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @keldar yep, did you remove your initial <ion-navbar> element? the <navbar> element shouldn't have any custom styling unless you have added any

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue creating an Ionic 4+ app (@ionic/angular 4.6.2), I wanted to add a login button and some other global stuffs in the header.

You can achieve that in a quite simple way.

Just add a **ion-header** containing a **ion-toolbar** in your **app.component.html** as a global header, like this:

```
<ion-header class="page-header">
   <ion-toolbar id="main-toolbar">
      <ion-title>
        <ion-label>{{ pageTitle }}</ion-label>
      </ion-title>
      <!-- add here all the things you need in your header --> 
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>
```

The problem here is that the "global header" will overlay the content of any page if you do only that. So has a workaround just add an empty **ion-header** containing an empty **ion-toolbar** on top of all your pages before the content tag, as follow:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar></ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <!-- your content here -->
</ion-content>
```

Doing that the "global header" will overlay the page header and the content will begin just after it.

Then you can manage all the code for your global header controls in your **app.component.ts** file.

I guess there could be some strange behaviour if the main header has a height greater than the "standard" toolbar height but with some nice CSS you should be able to fix it.

Furthermore, this workaround works fine with a side menu.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have since found out this is not possible. The only way to achieve this is by providing an `<ion-navbar>` and that will handle the back button automatically.

E.g.:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>

  <ion-title>Settings</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="hub-settings">
  <!-- content here -->
</ion-content>
```

Comment: So there is no way to achieve a "global" nav bar? You got to copy-and-paste `ion-navbar` everywhere or maybe put it in its own custom component and drop that in all pages?