# Partial views in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Do they exist, e.g. like we knew them from ng1 with ui-router, e.g. I got this html templates in my ionic 2 app:

```
<ion-header></..>

<ion-content></..>

<ion-footer></..>
```

Let's say I have 50 sites on my navController Navigational stack. Do I need to hardcode all these into each file? 25 years ago, we did this via iFrame - just saying..

Comment: Uppss, would be done via a directive import correct?

Comment: In order to avoid duplicating so much code, you can create your own **custom component** for the _header_, the _footer_ and every part of your app that could be used in more than one place. You can see how to do it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988)

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 3, create a component via CLI

```
ionic g component ComponentName
```

Add the component to the module of the page you want use. Let's say the page is `HomePage`, open `home.module.ts` and declare the component

```
import { ComponentNameComponent } from '../../components/component-name/component-name';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentNameComponent, //Component declaration
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ProfileProfilePage),
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Then you can use the component in the page view i.e. `home.html` like this

```
<component-name></component-name>
```