# Shared element in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have just started to play around with Ionic and trying to see how performat and flexible it is compared to native.

One of the standard use cases would be to add a toolbar with slider menu drawer and tabs.

When you do Android native development then you usually put pages in Fragments and then just reload some placeholder with a fragment keeping your toolbar and tabs view static.

However, all Ionic examples, that I have seen, re-implement a toolbar (`navbar`) in every page that tabs view opens.

For example:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="page1" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  ...
</ion-tabs>
```

And then the `page1` would be:

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-navbar>
     <ion-title>TITLE</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
   Welcome to page 1
</ion-content>
```

And this `ion-header` appears on every page.

Is it possible to make the header to be static so that I do not need to re-implement it in every page?
I tried to add it in the tabs template but that did not work and hid the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#comment64341268_37808988), @mhartington (from Ionic Team) says:

> **There is no way to create a global ion-navbar, as this is done on
>   purpose**. The point of having a navbar defined for each component is so
>   that we can properly animate the titles, navbar background color (if
>   you change them) and animate other properties needed.

And about creating a custom directive to avoid duplicating ion-navbar html code:

> That will still creat errors with how angular2 content projection
>   works. **We have several issues that have been open when people try this
>   and the best answer is to not do it**.