# including the common header bar for ionic 2/angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a ionic-2 header bar containing the **home or logout** button and **company logo** which is common for all the pages. How do i write a common function(@Injectable()), so that it will be very easy to include in all the pages instead of repeating the code.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar class="hide-border toolbar-btn-color" id="radio">
    <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Send Money</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="goHome()">
        <ion-icon ios="ios-home" md="md-home"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

In the every typescript file, i am repeating the function called gohome(). Is there any way to avoid this one?

Comment: i am getting this error : Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'custom-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'custom-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'custom-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by making header-component with configuration and then change configuration on different components accordingly.
Create custom header component.
 Lets Call it '**custom-header-component**' 
**custom-header-component.html**

```
<ion-navbar>
  <button *ngIf="header_data.ismenu" ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <button *ngIf="header_data.ishome" class="algo-header-home-icon" ion-button icon-only (click)="homeClick()">
    <ion-icon class="ion-home" name="home"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title class="header-title" [ngClass]="{'ishome-title': header_data.ishome,'ismeun-centre': !header_data.ishome}">
    {{header_data.title}}
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

**custom-header-component.ts**

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-header',
  templateUrl: 'custom-header.html'
})
export class CustomHeaderComponent {
  header_data: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  @Input()
  set header(header_data: any) {
    this.header_data=header_data;
  }
  get header() {
    return this.header_data;
  }
  homeClick() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
}
```

This custom-header-component takes configurations '**ismenu**' of type boolean, '**ishome**' of type boolean and '**title**' of type string. Now lets use this component in page component '**home**'. We want home page component to only have title and ismenu. Our code looks like this.
**'home.html'**

```
<ion-header><custom-header [header]="header_data"></custom-header></ion-header>
 <ion-content padding class="page-home">
   <p>Home Page</p>
 </ion-content>
```

**'home.ts'**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  header_data:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.header_data={ismenu:true,ishome:false,title:"Home"};
  }
}
<br/><br/>
```

Home page header would look like this.

[image]

Comment: i am getting this error on doing this: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'header' since it isn't a known property of 'custom-header'.
1. If 'custom-header' is an Angular component and it has 'header' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'custom-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<ion-header>
  <custom-header [ERROR ->][header]="header_data"></custom-header>

Comment: @amit gupta You also need to import `custom header component` and add it to declarations on app.module.ts

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I found a solution that is probably as bare-bones and simple as you can get.

As the Ionic team has stated, by DESIGN every page should have its own header.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    My content
</ion-content>
```

.. and we can't turn the header into a component because the *ion-header* needs to be a root-level component. So, the following **does not work**

```
<common-header></common-header>

<ion-content>
    My content
</ion-content>
```

... what I found DOES work is a simple combination of the two. Create a common-header component with a template that has everything, **but** the *ion-header* tag.

**common-header.ts**:

```
//Include Input to @angular/core
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: "common-header",
        templateUrl: "common-header.html"
    })
    export class CommonHeaderComponent {
        defaultTitle = "My default title";
        _title = this.defaultTitle;

        @Input()
        set title(newTitle: string) {
            newTitle = newTitle.trim();
            if (newTitle.length === 0) {
                newTitle = this.defaultTitle;
            }
            this._title = newTitle;
        }
        get title() {
            return this._title;
        }

        constructor() {
        }
    }
```

**common-header.html**:

```
<ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

Then finally, in your page where you want the header just include the common-header **inside** of a *ion-header* tag

```
<ion-header>
    <common-header [title]="'Title that is passed in'"></common-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 My content
</ion-content>
```

Comment: i am getting this error on doing this: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'header' since it isn't a known property of 'custom-header'.
1. If 'custom-header' is an Angular component and it has 'header' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'custom-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<ion-header>
  <custom-header [ERROR ->][header]="header_data"></custom-header>..

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988), @mhartington (from Ionic team) says:

> There is no way to create a global ion-navbar, as this is done on
>   purpose. The point of having a navbar defined for each component is so
>   that we can properly animate the titles, navbar background color (if
>   you change them) and animate other properties needed.

And about creating a custom directive to avoid duplicating the code in each view:

> That will still creat errors with how angular2 content projection
>   works. **We have several issues that have been open when people try this
>   and the best answer is to not do it.**