# Can I define ion-title outside ion-navbar (i.e. in ion-content) with ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to define **ion-header** section in only one separate file in order to use it for multiples screens.
But I want to define title **in each screen**.

With ionic 1, to do that, I define **ion-nav-title** in **ion-view** like explain here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavTitle/

It seems to not be possible with **ion-title** in **ion-content** with ionic 2: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Title/

I'm right? Is there a trick to do this?

Thanks,

Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `Input` variable. Just create a header page:

Html

```
<!-- ngIf to prevent a 'flashing' title, remove and see for yourself if you don't understand -->
<ion-header *ngIf="customTitle">
    <ion-navbar color="quintor">
        <button menuToggle ion-button>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>{{customTitle}}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar> 
</ion-header>
```

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header-page',
  templateUrl: 'header-page.html',
  inputs: ['title']
})
export class HeaderPage {

    //initialize if you remove the ngIf in html
    public customTitle: string; //= "";

    set title(value: string) {
       if(value) {
          this.customTitle = value;
       }
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

Then add the `HeaderPage` to your `@ngModule` under `declarations` (and `entryComponents`, depending on version)

Next, you can call it in any html file (no need to import the page whatsoever) like this:

`<header-page [title]="someVariable"></header-page>`

Or just

`<header-page title="This is my title"></header-page>`

*(not entirely sure if `title` is a reserverd term or not, if it is, just change it to something that isn't, `pageTitle` for example.)*

Comment: Please note, if this doesn't work, add in your code so we can debug it.

Comment: Thanks, I finally create a custom Component as you suggest.
Note that I also have to add custom css code to make it works properly (in Ionic 2.1): 
 
`header-page + ion-content {
    div.scroll-content, div.fixed-content {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to define ion-header section in only one separate file in order
>   to use it for multiples screens.

Just like you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988), **@mhartington** (from Ionic team) says:

> There is no way to create a global ion-navbar, as this is done on
>   purpose. The point of having a navbar defined for each component is so
>   that we can properly animate the titles, navbar background color (if
>   you change them) and animate other properties needed.

And about creating a custom directive to avoid duplicating ion-navbar html code:

> That will still create errors with how angular2 content projection
>   works. We have several issues that have been open when people try this
>   and the best answer is to not do it.

So even though that what you're trying to do totally makes sense, it may cause some issues later on, so you should avoid doing it :(