# Layout page in Ionic v2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'd like to have a layout page in my application (which is built with Ionic v2). As I want my navbar and sidemenu on every page, I think it's unnecessary to add those to all the page's of my project, right?

*As example: ASP.NET has master page's for website's, which contain the components that have to be on every page.*

Does anyone know if there's a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think it's unnecessary to add those to all the page's of my project,
>   right?

The sidemenu content needs to be added only once, in the `app.html` file. But regarding the navbar, as you can see in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988), @mhartington (from Ionic Team) says:

> **There is no way to create a global ion-navbar**, as this is done on purpose. The point of having a navbar defined for each component is so
>   that we can properly animate the titles, navbar background color (if
>   you change them) and animate other properties needed.

And about creating a custom directive to avoid duplicating ion-navbar html code (I guess this is what you were thinking of):

> That will still creat errors with how angular2 content projection
>   works. We have several issues that have been open when people try this
>   and **the best answer is to not do it**.

Answer (score -1):

There is an Ionic 2 sidemenu starter, which is a perfect starter for you t start with for your application like you need it to be.
[Follow this link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-sidemenu)

It has sidemenu component and you can build on top and add pages as you wish