# Navigation buttons inside top navbar with ionic-2-sidemenu app

Tags: angular, navigation, ionic2

I am trying to achieve a menu within the navbar of a sidemenu app, same as [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/both-side-menu-and-top-bar-tab-menu-like-tinder/19061) but with ionic 2: some navigation buttons into the top navbar.

I am new to ionic 2, so  I started a new app with `ionic start APP sidemenu --v2`
and now I understand that the navbar is in the header of every page.

So I would repeat my top navbar with my nav buttons on every page like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-buttons right>
  <button ion-button icon-only><!-- or your method, this is for closing a modal -->
     <ion-icon name="md-person"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
<ion-buttons right>
  <button ion-button icon-only><!-- or your method, this is for closing a modal -->
     <ion-icon name="ios-search"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

but it's not clean.

Is there a way to separate this navbar in a menu.html file or should I copy my buttons in every page's header?

What code do I need to start a mixed sidemenu/tabs? I am new to Angular 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making sure I understand the question right: you want a way for all of the code you posted above to go on every page without having to repeat the code?

Answer: component

You can just make a component, and use the code above as the component's template. If you were to make the component's selector to be 'navbar' for example, then instead of all of the above code, you would then just put

```
<navbar></navbar>
```

at the top of every page that needs the navbar.

We use ionic to build our apps at work, and this is exactly what we do. In general, whether it be ionic or angular, if you want to reuse some code without copying and pasting it everywhere, then components are your answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you help me with to properly declare the component (which file) ?

Comment: you create the component in a typescript file. You can define the template, your html above, in an html file. Basic angular components. I'm not going to explain to you how to create an angular component in a comment on SO because the internet is full of examples. The guides on the angular.io website are also extremely helpul.

Comment: Check out the following post. Some kind person had the patience to type out a bunch of code in their answer to the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @HaydenBraxton but mhartington commented with a warning, saying this will create error with angular 2...what do you think ?

Comment: hey sorry for the confusion. So what he was saying is that there's no way to put the navbar markup in just one place in the code and have it apply to all pages in the app. I'm sure there is actually a way, but that's besides the point. What I am saying to do and what he was saying is the same thing. create a component, you could call it navbar if you wanted, and then on every page that needs a navbar, you'll have to put that component at the top of the page.

Comment: So if you follow what that guy does in the other post, which is what I am suggesting as well, you'll end up putting `<navbar></navbar>` at the top of every page in the app that needs a navbar. Put currently, there is no [easy] way to just put <navbar></navbar> in only one place in the app and have it apply to every page in the app. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok I understand, that makes sense. We have to repeat `<navbar></navbar>` at the top of every page. But it's not much !  I am still really trying to figure out angular2 and I haven't written the component yet...