# global function in Ionic 2 / Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

How can I setup a global function that can be accessed throughout all views?

In app.component.ts I added a simple method

```
  openShare() {console.log("button clicked")}
```

and then in my nav I have

```
  <button ion-button right (click)="openShare()">
  <ion-icon name="md-share"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

When I try to access this from any page I get the following.

```
self.context.openShare is not a function
```

It does however execute fine if I put it directly in the constructor (e.g this.openShare(); ), but when calling from any page using a (click) function it just doesn't work.

Is app.component.ts not global? I thought this is where I would place it, but maybe I am missing something.

Basically its a function for a simple button on the nav, I need it to be global though since its used on every page.

Any help would be appreciated, still figuring Ionic 2 out.

Comment: Try a custom directive.

Comment: Any example code how I would do this?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: @HarishKommuri - This might also work. If anyone has a simple example would be appreciated. I am more visual, not asking to write the code just a simple example on a click method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Directive`.

Try as follows.

Put the following code in separate directive file. (social-sharing.directive.ts);

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[socialSharing]'
})
export class SocialSharing {

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    // Your click functionality
  }
}
```

Import it into `app.module.ts` and than add to `declarations`.

In HTML, just add `attribute` to any element which is the `selector` in your directive file.

```
<button ion-button right socialSharing>
 <ion-icon name="md-share"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

**Additional Info:**

Passing values from component to directive.

***home.html***

```
  <button ion-button right [socialSharing]="property">
    <ion-icon name="md-share"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

***home.component.ts***

```
 export class HomePage {

   property: string = 'some url';
    constructor() {}
 }
```

***social-sharing.directive.ts***

Import `Input` along with others from `@angular/core`.

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
   selector: '[socialSharing]'
})

export class SocialSharing {
  @Input('socialSharing') str: string;

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
     console.log(this.str);
  }
};

  ngAfterInit() {
     console.log(this.str);
  };
}
```

Using Element in Directive:

***social-sharing.directive.ts***

Import `ElementRef` along with others from `@angular/core`

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

 @Directive({
   selector: '[socialSharing]'
 })

 export class SocialSharing {

   // Add ElementRef to constructor

   constructor(el: ElementRef) {};

   ngOnInit() {
      let elRef = this.el.nativeElement;
      console.log(elRef.innerHTML);        
   };
 }
```

Comment: - Hey thank you.  This actually worked perfect. A lot of posts for people wanting to know how to do this. Hopefully they find your answer here.  Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily do that using `Providers`.When you need to use that functionality (or provider), you just need to `inject` it into your related component.That is it.

**Method 1:**

You can create a Provider using CLI.

```
> ionic g provider YourProvider
```

*your-provider.ts*

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class YourProvider {

      constructor() {
      }

       openShare() {console.log("button clicked")} 
    }
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { YourProvider } from "../pages/path";

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
      ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
       ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        ],
      providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },YourProvider  ]
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

*your-view.ts*

```
       import { YourProvider } from '../../providers/your-provider';

        export class YourViewPage{

          constructor(public yourProvider : YourProvider) {

          }

        openShare(){
           this.yourProvider.openShare(); 
        }
```

**Method 2:** Creat an `abstract` base class.

*my-base-class.ts*

```
export abstract class MyBaseClass {

  constructor() {
  }

  protected openShare():void {
    console.log("button clicked"); 
  }

}
```

*my-view.ts*

```
export class MyViewPage extends MyBaseClass {
  constructor()
  {
     super();
  }

       openShare(){
               super.openShare(); 
            }
  }
```

Comment: hmm.. yeah this is kind of how I set things up now, but for a simple function seems like too many imports over 20 pages.  Is this the only way?  This is for a button in the nav header so basically called on every page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Interesting with the abstract class, will give this a try.

Comment: sure.hope you'll share the result with us :)

Answer (score 3):

Just like @Sampath mentioned, one way would be to use a custom provider. But since you method is just a simple one, I think you can use [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) instead. It'd be like this:

In your `app.component.ts` file, subscribe to the new event:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events, ...) {

  // ...

  events.subscribe('social:share', () => {

    // your code...
    console.log("button clicked");

  });

}
```

And then in any other page, just publish the event to execute that logic:

```
function anotherPageMethod() {
  this.events.publish('social:share');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this might work.  Still though - I can't believe something so global as a nav bar, there is no simple way to declare common methods. So much for keeping it DRY. Was simple in Ionic 1. Oh well -  Really appreciate the help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, have a look at using shared module, that in turn includes a shared component

Create a custom component that you will use as your shared component by using the Ionic CLI as follows:

ionic g component components/nameofcomponent

Where nameofcomponent is the name you want to use for your shared component

[See this article for example](https://bobcares.com/blog/custom-component-and-shared-module-in-ionic/), on how to create a shared module to include your shared component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).