# ionic2 AlertController, how to return the buttons clicked value from method

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I m fairly new in `Typescript`, I have following code in provider

```
...
confirm(message, title=""){
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: title || "Please confirm",
            message: message,
            buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Yes',
                  handler: () => {
                    return true;
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'No',
                  handler: () => {
                    return false;
                  }
                }
              ]
        });

        confirm.present();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

There is a button in a page, which calls a function `deleteItems`

```
deleteItems(){
    this.popup.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item");
    if(this.popup.isTrue == true){
          //delete items
     }

}
```

I want the `confirm` method to return true or false depending upon the button "Yes" or "No" clicked.

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Both buttons take a handler each. I would use the handlers to set `a`.

Define arrow functions

```
a:boolean;
onYesHandler = ()=>{
   this.a = true;
}

onNoHandler = () =>{
   this.a = false;
}
```

let `confirm` function take the handlers along with message:

```
confirm(message, yesHandler,noHandler,title=""){
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: title || "Please confirm",
            message: message,
            buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Yes',
                  handler: yesHandler
                },
                {
                  text: 'No',
                  handler: noHandler
                }
              ]
        });

        confirm.present();
    }
```

call the `confirm` function:

```
this.popup.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item",this.onYesHandler,this.onNoHandler);
```

Comment: I want to make alert simpler so I created the provider, if I have to create arrow function every page where alert is used, then its better i use `let confirm .....` every where I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as shown below.

**Note:** Creating an UI related things with `Provider` is treated as *Anti-Pattern* on Ionic2.Because `provider` is to handle service related use cases.Keep that in mind too.

Would you like to see the alternative? Please see [**2nd Method of my answer here**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164262/global-function-in-ionic-2-angular-2/43164323#43164323)In other words you can use a `base class` for handling it.

```
 isTrue:boolean=null;

    constructor(){}

    confirm(message, title=""){
            let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: title || "Please confirm",
                message: message,
                buttons: [
                    {
                      text: 'Yes',
                       handler: data => {
                             this.isTrue=true;
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      text: 'No',
                     handler: data => {
                              this.isTrue=false;
                      }
                    }
                  ]
            });

            confirm.present();
        }
```

Comment: So in page we will check `if(this.popup.isTrue==true)` ??  Instead of using it in provider, do you have some better way??, I don't want to use whole block whenever I need to use alert or confirm

Comment: This didn't work, When a button is clicked, it calls a method `deleteItems()`, that executes `this.popup.confirm(...)` method. So I get `false`value when method `deleteItems` is executed (when popup is shown). But I want it to have further action (delete or just do nothing), when `Yes` button in popup alert is clicked.

Comment: now, what is the value of this `if(this.popup.isTrue == true){` when you press the `Yes` button inside the confirm?

Comment: its `false` as `confirm` method is executed as soon as `deleteItems` is called, Clicking yes doesn't yield everything, because we want something to happen  only if "Yes" is clicked,

Comment: can you put a lightweight version of your use case on Git repo? Then we can play with it no.