# creating a common header element for ionic app throws error in --prod build

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have been working on an ionic 3 app, which has some pages with a common header only with some minor difference of elements inside the header. To avoid code duplication and keep myself DRY I tried to create a reusable component for this header and included it in every page required.

In this component, I have few properties, which I am using to control the differences of elements via property binding. Everything works fine in the development build. But today when I tried to create a --prod build, it shows me the following error.

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'isHome' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-header'.
1. If 'ion-header' is an Angular component and it has 'isHome' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header clean-header [ERROR ->][isHome]="true" (refresh)="refresh($event);"></ion-header>
```

I'll attach the code below, individual files, I understand this is an issue because of my misunderstanding of angular4 / ionic3's dependency injection and template binding structure. But I can't understand the given error, I tried the 3 solutions listed in the error itself, But I am still missing something and the error stays the same.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { LaunchNavigator} from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Header } from '../pages/header/header';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {AssignmentDetailPage} from '../pages/assignment-detail/assignment-detail';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import {ReportIssuePage} from '../pages/report-issue/report-issue';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { BaseUrl, Base } from './config/config.constants';
import { LoadingInterceptor } from '../interceptors/loading.interceptor';
import { DataStoreProvider } from '../providers/data-store/data-store';
import { HomeServiceProvider } from '../providers/home-service/home-service';
import { SessionInterceptor } from '../interceptors/session.interceptor';
import { AssignmentStatusProvider } from '../providers/assignment-status/assignment-status';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { File} from '@ionic-native/file';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    Header,
    AssignmentDetailPage,
    ReportIssuePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      mode : 'md',
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    AssignmentDetailPage,
    ReportIssuePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    {provide:Base, useValue:BaseUrl},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoadingInterceptor, multi:true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: SessionInterceptor, multi:true},
    AuthServiceProvider,
    DataStoreProvider,
    Camera,
    File,
    HomeServiceProvider,
    AssignmentStatusProvider,
    LaunchNavigator,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

header.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Header } from './header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Header,
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    Header
  ]
})
export class HeaderModule {}
```

header.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { AlertController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { HomeServiceProvider } from '../../providers/home-service/home-service';

@Component({
  selector: '[clean-header]',
  templateUrl: 'header.html',
})
export class Header {
  @Input() isHome: boolean = false;
  @Output() refresh: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  public user: any;
  constructor(public Auth: AuthServiceProvider, public nav: NavController,
     public alertCtrl: AlertController, public HomeService: HomeServiceProvider) {

    this.user = Auth.getUserData();
  }
```

header.html

```
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton>
    <div text-center>
    <img class="header-logo" src="./assets/imgs/clean_connect.png" alt="Logo of clean connect">
    </div>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-8>
          <div class="name-section">
            <h4 class="header-username">{{user.userName | uppercase}}</h4>
            <p>{{user.firstName +', '+ user.lastName}}</p>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4 class="nav-controls">
          <a (click)="refreshData()" *ngIf="isHome"><img src="./assets/imgs/ic_refresh.png"   alt="Logo of Refresh"></a>
          <a (click)="goHome();" *ngIf="!isHome"><img src="./assets/imgs/home.png"   alt="Logo of Home"></a>
          <a (click)="logout()"><img src="./assets/imgs/logout.png"   alt="Logo of Logout"></a>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2 class="nav-controls">

        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-navbar>
```

finally I am using this component in other places like this,

home.html

```
<ion-header clean-header [isHome]="true" (refresh)="refresh($event);"></ion-header>
<ion-content>
```

I tried to use it as a custom element rather than an attribute, But it doesn't produce the desired layout due to an custom element sits between ion-header and ion-content, and I can't find the way to use transclusion like the way in angular1.

I know this question is pretty long, But I can't make a working fiddle. can anyone help me?

Comment: Doing this is not recommended by the Ionic team. Please take a look at **[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988)**

Comment: @sebaferreras so I have to keep the duplicate code everywhere?. I pity choosing the ionic framework, which doesn't encourage DRY concepts. I don't see any valid point for not accepting the above behavior.

Comment: Please don't get the wrong idea; **It does encourage DRY concepts**, but there're a lot of things going on behind the scenes to animate the behavior of the app and make it look like a native app from the UI/UX point of view. You'd need to have a deep knowledge of Ionic's internal details to modify some other parts of the code (like page transitions) to make everything work properly with your header component, so probably the best advice is not to use a custom component there...

Comment: @sebaferreras Thanks for your kind advice, Can you please make your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? I am pretty sure your comment answers my question directly, so it can qualify as a valid answer.

Comment: Glad to help :) I think I shouldn't add this as an answer since it doesn't fix the error of the OP; it's just a suggestion about avoiding that specific scenario.

Comment: @sebaferreras I had to do it anyway and I found a way to achieve it, you can see it in my own answer below. Thanks for your time and help. I'll update the answer if I encounter any issues due to this custom header module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

> But based on the recommendations of the ionic team it is wise not to
>   put common header instead put headers on every page due to ionic
>   internal designs decisions. Thanks for [sebaferreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915438/sebaferreras)'s advice. I don't recommend anyone doing the below without considering the cost. But I wanted to demonstrate it is possible.

.

But I still want to implement it because my ionic headers have some mid-level complex functions and I can't afford to copy them on every single page I use. I implemented it as below,

1) remove any reference to the module / component.ts from app.module.ts, remove any imports of the component from app.module.ts,

2) Import IonicModule in the import section of your header (reusable) module (header,module.ts)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Header } from './header';
import {IonicModule} from "ionic-angular";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Header,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule
  ],
  exports: [
    Header
  ]
})
export class HeaderModule {}
```

then import the HeaderModule in every other page's module, remember not in the component.ts file but in the module of that file.

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';
import {HeaderModule} from "../header/header.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    HeaderModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

this works as expected, I don't notice any side effects and for that animations part, our current project doesn't care much about animating the title, so if it doesn't work its not a problem for my use case. Check accordingly for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for adding the comment in your answer :) Also please take a look **[at this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164262/global-function-in-ionic-2-angular-2)** in order to see how you could create a global function to be used anywhere in the app by just adding an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: notwithstanding the advice above about best practice, I had a similar error creating a component, so providing answer for others who search on the error.
In my case I just had a plain old component and I had the same error, except it complained about ion-label. The first time this took me a fair bit of digging and trial and error to work out. I found the documentation less than clear on the topic, or maybe I just didn't manage to google the right thing.*

You need to import `IonicModule` into your `header.module.ts` as well as `app.module.ts`, i.e.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Header } from './header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Header,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule      // <-- add here
  ],
  exports: [
    Header
  ]
})
export class HeaderModule {}
```

Note the live reload may miss this change the first time, so kill and restart ionic serve to make sure.

The following bug report comments helped me work it out:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14288#issuecomment-282531453
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-0-shared-component/91727/2