# Get the same layout for all Ionic 3 pages

Tags: layout, ionic-framework, header, ionic3

I started to work with Ionic 3, and I use the tabs starter layout.
As the tabs, displayed on all pages, I want to get a layout, with for example a header with a logo, a button, and a text on it.

At the time, I moved `<ion-header>` from my pages (.html file) to tabs.html, and it seems to work, but I don't think it's the good way.

This is my tabs.html :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>My App</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

By the way, by doing this, there are no margin between my header and my content (See the screenshot)
[image]

Can you explain me why this margin, and the best way to get a layout?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 - global NavBar for the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app)

Comment: You could fix the issue related to the margin by getting the instance of the content, and calling `content.resize()` in the `ionViewDidLoad` callback, but this would be just a horrible workaround. The best answer is just to add the header on each page :)

Comment: Thanks. But it's annoying when you have 10 pages, and the header is complex (buttons, input, ...)

Comment: I know, but Ionic team needed to keep things as flexible as possible, and they made this decision. IMHO, this allow us to build mobile apps with beautiful animations and visual effects, which make our apps to feel really _native_

Answer (score 0):

Referring to a member of the Ionic team

> Having a different header for each page is a design decision we've
>   made. In Ionic 1, a common issue was that having a single
>   header/navbar wasn't flexible enough for people.  You couldn't really
>   do anything dynamic like change header color, and animations were very
>   difficult to coordinate.
>
> The way ionic 2 handles things now is much better.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/same-header-for-all-pages/75736