# Ionic custom component overlapping content

Tags: html, css, ionic2, ionic3

I created custom component, which is showing footer (need to have same footer on many pages). That's code of it:

```
<ion-footer class="fh">
  <ion-toolbar>
    Footer
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

And CSS:

```
.fh .toolbar-background{
  background-color: blue;
}

.fh ion-toolbar{
  min-height: 15em;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 20em;
}
```

For example , this component named footer-h

I'd like to use it in pages, so:

```
<ion-header>
...
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
...
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
<footer-h></footer-h>
```

It works, i mean footer shows, but there is problem that it's overlapping content (rest of items on list under footer and can't scroll).

But when I'll write page like that:

```
<ion-header>
...
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
...
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer class="fh">
  <ion-toolbar>
    Footer
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

everything is working, list is scrollable, nothing is overlaps.

Comment: In this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988) you can see that creating a global navbar is not recommended in Ionic, and I think the same happens with the `ion-footer` (since it's also outside of the `ion-content`). It may sound ugly an not DRY at all, but AFAIK the recommended way is to keep that code duplicated in all the pages.

Comment: Hmm, but it's little uncomfortable to change x pages everytime :/

Comment: Yeah, I know... What happens if you include your custom component but inside of the footer like this: `<ion-footer><ion-toolbar>...yourComponentHere...</ion-toolbar></ion-footer>`? Maybe that will help Ionic to calculate the height of the content since the `ion-footer` is there, and you can still modify the content of all the footers by updating your custom component...

Comment: Yea, that's working. I didn't think about this. Just write an answer, i'll choose it as solution.

Comment: Done! Glad to hear that it's working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like you can see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988), it seems like using custom components for the navbar or the footer may lead to some bugs, since it may affect the way the height of the `ion-content` is calculated.

That being said, one way to fix your issue would be to place your custom component inside of the `ion-footer` element, so that **Ionic could calculate the height of the content since the ion-footer is there, and you can still modify the content of all the footers by just updating your custom component**:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <!-- ...yourComponentHere... -->
  </ion-toolba‌​r>
</ion-footer>
```