# How to keep both DOM elements and template string of a component in angular2 & ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I use ionic2 & angular2 to build app, I want to define a custom component like ion-navbar, which can append title and buttons in it, just like:

```html
<t-nav>
  <t-title>title for custom nav</t-title>
  <t-buttons></t-buttons>
</t-nav>
```

with a custom component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 't-nav',
  template: '<div>dummy</div><div>dummy</div>'
})
export class TNav {
}
```

But after ionic build, the content in t-nav was missing, only remains

```html
<t-nav>
<div>dummy</div><div>dummy</div>
</t-nav>
```

So can anybody tell me how does the angular2 framework keep DOM elements in ion-nav and ion-buttons while template is not empty?

Some code from ionic-angular package, nav.js, it seems template is not empty

```js
Navbar.decorators = [
    { type: Component, args: [{
                selector: 'ion-navbar',
                template: '<div class="toolbar-background" [ngClass]="\'toolbar-background-\' + _mode"></div>' +
                    '<button (click)="backButtonClick($event)" ion-button="bar-button" class="back-button" [ngClass]="\'back-button-\' + _mode" [hidden]="_hideBb">' +
                    '<ion-icon class="back-button-icon" [ngClass]="\'back-button-icon-\' + _mode" [name]="_bbIcon"></ion-icon>' +
                    '<span class="back-button-text" [ngClass]="\'back-button-text-\' + _mode">{{_backText}}</span>' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '<ng-content select="[menuToggle],ion-buttons[left]"></ng-content>' +
                    '<ng-content select="ion-buttons[start]"></ng-content>' +
                    '<ng-content select="ion-buttons[end],ion-buttons[right]"></ng-content>' +
                    '<div class="toolbar-content" [ngClass]="\'toolbar-content-\' + _mode">' +
                    '<ng-content></ng-content>' +
                    '</div>',
                host: {
                    '[hidden]': '_hidden',
                    'class': 'toolbar',
                    '[class.statusbar-padding]': '_sbPadding'
                }
            },] },
];
```

and also in html we can nest elements like

```html
<ion-navbar>
     <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
       <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
     </button>

     <ion-title>
       Page Title
     </ion-title>

     <ion-buttons end>
       <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openModal()">
         <ion-icon name="options"></ion-icon>
       </button>
     </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 't-nav',
  template: '<div>dummy</div><div>dummy</div>'
})
export class TNav {
}
```

That tells Angular that the *template* of the component is just `<div>dummy</div><div>dummy</div>`. If you want to *transclude* the html elements inside of the `t-nav`, you need to add `<ng-content></ng-content>` like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 't-nav',
  template: `<!-- Dumy div -->
             <div>dummy</div>
             <!-- Content included beetween <t-nav>...</t-nav> -->
             <ng-content></ng-content>
             <!-- Another dummy div -->
             <div>dummy</div>`
})
export class TNav {
}
```

That will tell Agular to put whatever HTML elements are inside of the `<t-nav>...</t-nav>` (like `t-title` and `t-buttons`) where the `ng-content` is.

---

**IMPORTANT**: Just like you can see in **[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988)** Mark Hartington from Ionic Team does not recommed to use a custom component as the navbar because it may lead to several issues and bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! For some reason, our team need to custom ionic nav bar's appearance, maybe we can find another way to achieve this.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Yes, you can give that a try, and if you see any issues, please let us know so we can take a look and see how that can be fixed...