# How may I create a dynamic nav bar with a common button and title in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an IONIC-3 application, whether I want a dynamic nav bar with a title and a common button. For this reason, I have created a .ts file named 
commonBtn.ts. Here is the code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
@Component({
  selector: 'common-button',
  templateUrl: 'commonBtn.html'

})
export class CommonBtnPage {
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }
   logOut() {
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
   }
}
```

And its html is :-

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>       I want to create a dynamic name       </ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logOut()">
                <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Now, my question is that, How may I change the title name dynamically means when user come into "Home Page", title will be "Home" or user come into "About" page, title will be "About".

We can manage this in ionic v1 via $rootScope but here in Ionic v3, how can I resolve this ?

Also I am giving the html of Home page

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <common-button></common-button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
     <button ion-button (click) = 'clickHere()'> Click </button>
</ion-content>
```

Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: not sure how you think nesting `ion-header` will work?

Comment: Any alternative solution ?

Comment: look at this https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Navbar/ and try to ask this Ionic forum https://forum.ionicframework.com/

Comment: Please notice that using a custom component as the header of the app **is not recommended according to Ionic team** and may produce some bugs/issues ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988))

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you need to use [`Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator. Check [Component Interactions](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

In CommonBtnPage,

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
@Component({
  selector: 'common-button',
  templateUrl: 'commonBtn.html'

})
export class CommonBtnPage {

   @Input()title:string;//here

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }
   logOut() {
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
   }
}
```

In the html, set the title,

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logOut()">
                <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

You can set the component and send the title as:

```
<common-button [title]="'home'"></common-button>
```