# Ionic2 custom components in Pages

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic as a PWA. I use pages for navigation and I developed a component called `common-header` which displays the username and page name. It accepts an input called `HeaderTitle` and it displays the title. The component is declared in `components.module.ts` and I have imported the `componentmodule` in my `PageModule`. When I use the component in my page the component css styles does not work as expected.

If I remove the declaration of CommonHeader component in componentmodule and define in pagemodule the UI looks good.

This is the html code of CommonHeader.

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton>
      <ion-title>
         {{UserName}}
      </ion-title>
      <ion-title>
         {{HeaderTitle}}
      </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

Below is the Html code of my page

```
<ion-header>
   <tr-header [HeaderTitle]="HeaderTitle"></tr-header>
 </ion-header>

 <ion-content padding>
     Page Content
 </ion-content>
```

The problem is CSS looks weird like the button does not have proper color/height. All this happens if I declare a component in componentmodule.ts and use the componentmodule file in my page module.

If I declare the component in my page module only it works great. But I need my custom component to be used in all the pages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988)**

Comment: Thank you...I will take a look at it

Comment: Try to import `IonicPageModule` in your `component.module.ts` like this:`@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicPageModule]
})`